# Duplicated tags 'transpose' and 'transposition'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Are the tags below duplicated?

If so, should one of them be removed and/or become a synonym for the other?

If not, should we modify the description to highlight the differences?

[transposition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transposition) (52 questions, 9 this year):
The shifting of a melody, a harmonic progression or an entire musical piece to another key, while maintaining the same tone structure, i.e. the same succession of whole tones and semitones and remaini…

[transpose](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transpose) (7 questions, 3 this year):
To transpose a fragment of music means to shift it into another key, maintaining the same intervals between the notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've merged the latter into the former (after untagging one that wasn't relevant).  Good catch!